# node-sass@3.8.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js` Failed at the node-sass@3.6.0 postinstall script 'node scripts/build.js' Exit status 1

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

[image]when I am running gulp serve for my angularjs fuse project. this error will be shown.

C:\wamp\www\bank_admin_post_login\Fuse-1.4.1-demo>gulp serve

C:\wamp\www\bank_admin_post_login\Fuse-1.4.1-demo>npm rebuild node-sass

I am running above commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try install an ancient version of Node JS, I suggest you 4.2.2